# How to inherit from ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

So I found some code that I am trying to get working. I am new to Android/Exclipse/Java and still trying to wrap my head around the whole thing. However, I am starring myself blind.

Say I have this:

```
private class RSSListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyRSSItem> {
  private List<MyRSSItem> objects = null;        
  public RSSListAdapter(Context context, int viewid, List<MyRSSItem> objects) {
    super(context, viewid, objects);                       
    this.objects = objects;            
  }
}
```

and then elsewhere this:

```
myRssAdapter = new RSSListAdapter(thisActivityContext, newsListView, myItemsDataArrayList);
```

where `myItemsDataArrayList` is declared like this:

```
ArrayList<MyRSSItem> myItemsDataArrayList = new ArrayList<MyRSSItem>();
```

I get this error:

> The constructor News.RSSListAdaptor(Context, ListView, ArrayList) is undefined

Of course I have tried Google, but, well, no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constructor's definition is this:

```
public RSSListAdapter(Context context, int viewid, List<MyRSSItem> objects) {
```

This means it accepts in only a `Context`, an `int`, and a `List <MyRSSItem>`

However, you call the constructor with these arguments:

```
new RSSListAdapter(thisActivityContext, newsListView, myItemsDataArrayList);
```

the *second* argument is a `newsListView`, which isn't an `int`, it is a `ListView`. They are not the same type, hence the compile-time error.

If you change to `android.R.id.text1`, it should work, since that is a valid TextView id, like the [superclass constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E%29) requires.

And definitely don't forget to set the `ListView`'s adapter to your `RSSListAdapter` after creating it.

For more detailed info, [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) tutorial is pretty helpful.

Comment: OMG + Doh! + I did say I was starring myself blind. I was investigating all things regarding Java constructors instead of... Well, let us not dwell more on than for my sake. Thanks! :)